# How to get tox to use a Python interpreter on a specifc path

Tags: python, tox

I'm using tox version 4.12.0, and have `env_list = py{3.8,3.9}-pytest5`. This successfully finds and uses the OS-supplied Python 3.9 to run those tests, but skips testing with Python 3.8 because it can't find an interpreter. (This is correct behaviour so far: I have no Python 3.8 interpreter in my path and do not want one in my path.)

So I'd like to get tox to use a Python interpreter on a specifc path, in this case one compiled with `pythonz`: `/home/cjs/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.8.18/bin/python3`. However, when I add a `base_python` setting for this:

```
base_python =
    py3.8: /home/cjs/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.8.18/bin/python3
```

It gives me the following complaint:

```
py3.8-pytest5: failed with env name py3.8-pytest5 conflicting with base python /home/cjs/.pythonz/pythons/CPython-3.8.18/bin/python3
```

I get the same complaint even if I change the executable name at the end of the path to `python3.8` (which also exists in that directory). I've looked at the documentation for [`ignore_python_base_conflict`](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#ignore_base_python_conflict), which I don't really understand, and tried both `true` and `false` settings of that variable, but it seems to make no difference.

How do I tell tox to use a specific Python interpreter on a specific path for a particular test?

Bonus points if you can tell me how to easily set this path at runtime, since for other users it's obviously not going to be under `/home/cjs/...`.

Comment: There was a plugin, but I guess it will not work with tox 4+: https://pypi.org/project/tox-interpreters/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has [been confirmed](https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues/3191#issuecomment-1896267595) to be a bug in tox; it should accept a full path to a Python interpreter and use it.